# One page per sheet property in JasperReports

Tags: excel, jasper-reports, xls

I have a requirement where I have to design a report in JasperReports. The report has 4 sheets. The first sheet has 5 pages and similarly other sheets has one or two pages.The problem that I am facing is if I use the **net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet** property and set it to ***true***, then all the pages comes in different sheets. I need to design the report in such a manner that some  pages will come in a same sheet and some pages in a different sheet.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: So do you have 4 separate Report files you are using?

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you Have 4 separate reports that you are batch exporting, then in each report you need to set `Ignore Pagination` to `true` (it is an attribute in the jasperReport tag at the beggining of the jrxml file, the attribute looks like `isIgnorePagination="true"`).

To actually export it should look similar to this:

```
List<JasperPrint> jasperPrintList = new ArrayList<JasperPrint>();
jasperPrintList.add(JasperFillManager.fillReport("report1.jasper", params1));
jasperPrintList.add(JasperFillManager.fillReport("report2.jasper", params2));
jasperPrintList.add(JasperFillManager.fillReport("report3.jasper", params3));
jasperPrintList.add(JasperFillManager.fillReport("report4.jasper", params4));

JRXlsExporter exporter = new JRXlsExporter();

exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, jasperPrintList);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, "BatchExportReport.xls");
exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, Boolean.TRUE);

exporter.exportReport();
```

To set the sheet names, take a look at [Dynamic Sheet Names](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/xlsfeatures/index.html#dynamicSheetNames) example they have at JasperForge.

---

According to your comment you are wanting to use the same report templates to export to multiple formats. With excel being the only one that needs to ignore pagination. What you can do is set via a parameter at runtime instead of hardcoded in the report. So add the following to the params1,params2,params3,and params4:

```
if(exportFormat == EXCEL) {
   params1.put(JRParameter.IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION, Boolean.TRUE);
   params2.put(JRParameter.IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION, Boolean.TRUE);
   params3.put(JRParameter.IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION, Boolean.TRUE);
   params4.put(JRParameter.IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION, Boolean.TRUE);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However I am not sure if I have made my issue clear.Let me give you a clear requirement.  THe template that I have been given is in xls format and has  4 diffrent tabs/sheets.The issue would have been solved if this was only the case by using 3 subreports and setting one page per sheet property.However the designing got completed when I realized that the first tab/sheet itself has 5 pages.So setting the one page per sheet property would make these pages come in different tab/sheets which is not what I want. Is there any way to accomplish this requirement?

Comment: I must be missing something, because a page does not really mean anything in the context of Excel Spreadsheet. I think you will have to rework that first report that is 5 pages, so that it is a single page. Maybe you you could use a some subreport trickery to pull it off. You could place the report as a subreport in the detail section  of a new top level report. Set the ignore pagination to True on both, then export it.

Comment: Thanx for the reply.Yes, it works fine in Excel export with your suggestion. However for other export like pdf and rtf it generates a long single page when i set the ignore pagination to true. I need to design the report such that it is printable format in excel(here i assume we have options to set the print format) and most importantly in pdf and rtf. Is there any property that I can set or add ?