# Merge two report template into one report with two excel sheet using jrxml

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I have two jrxml template to create two reports. Is it possible to create a new report with these template as two excel sheet in one report with the help of jrxml template alone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [One page per sheet property in JasperReports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752117/one-page-per-sheet-property-in-jasperreports) & [Jaspererports iReport: split report into several excel sheets on export](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32368386/876298) & [One excel Sheet for each subreport (No groups in the main report)jaspersoft iReport](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15410951/876298) & [How to export to multiple sheets in excel from jasper report](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34808741/876298)

Comment: i cant edit the java file here is it possible by using only jrxml